# ng-show doesn't work on routescope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

Could someone explain this strange angularjs behaviour
CODE HTML

```
    <button 
     ng-show="!$root.commandsHide"
    >My Button</button>

    {{$root.commandsHide}}
```

OPTPUT contains:

```
"My Button" and true
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your controller logic please.